# How can two derived classes share the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T> logging framework / How to manually create ILogger<T> without DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core the default resolver will resolve `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<MyClass>` in the controller.

Suppose I create a fresh .NET Standard library that is called from the controller.

How do I pass a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` instance into it?

- How do I create a `new()` instance of my class if `ILogger<MyClass2>` is required?
- Can C# create a manual automapping for `ILogger<T>`, which I can pass into my library?

Comment: using `new` beats the purpose of having an Dependency Injection Framework in the first place

Comment: In any case, `Logger<T>` (form the logger package) is just a wrapper class around `ILoggerFactory`, see the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerOfT.cs#L29). But if you want use `ILogger<T>`in your library you are **STRONGLY** advised to use dependency injection all the way down, since you don't have to bother about concrete types & instantiation in your code, the DI/Application will do it and can replace it with any other implementation (i.e. library upgrade or drop in replacement)

Comment: @Tseng how do I use DI all the way down? I know how to consume DI, but not call a class using DI

Comment: You don't need to call any concrete classes in your libraries. Just use the interface (by injecting in constructor). Everything else is configured in the application (i.e. in ASP.NET Core app by configuring the loggers, or doing it manually in the main application, i.e by calling `.AddLogging` method on  `IServiceCollection`). Or manually register it like [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L32-L49), but thats not advisable as it may change in future versions and you'd need to update your code

Answer (score 4):

There are times when Dependency Injection isn't available - or when you're in a context where you shouldn't be using DI (such as a Unit Test, where you're meant to explicitly define each injected service), ditto some forms of Integration testing.

In those cases - if you don't care about logging (such as when prototyping or experimenting) then use the `NullLogger`, which is built-in to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` (which is the *common* NuGet package that all MEL-using projects must reference, so it's guaranteed to be available).

For example, if you have a service implementation that requires a non-null `ILogger<T>`:

```
public interface IEncabulatorService
{
    void Foo();
}

public class TurboEncabulatorService : IEncabulatorService
{
    private readonly ILogger log;

    public TurboEncabulatorService( ILogger<TurboEncabulatorService> log )
    {
        this.log = log ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(log));
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        this.log.LogInformation( "Foo was invoked." );
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate this with the `NullLogger` dummy logger (for example, in a Unit testing project) like so:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging; // This namespace must be imported because it uses extension-methods.
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions;

[TestClass]
public class MyTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestEncabulator()
    {
        ILogger<TurboEncabulatorService> log = NullLoggerFactory.Instance.CreateLogger<TurboEncabulatorService>()

        IEncabulatorService service = new TurboEncabulatorService( log );
    }
}
```

If you *do* care about what is logged, then unfortunately you do need to implement your own `ILoggerFactory` (and log to some internal buffer), but you do not need to provide your own `CreateLogger<T>()` method to create strongly-typed `ILogger<T>` instances, as that's provided for-free in the MEL library as an extension method.

### Regarding subclasses

You mentioned in your post "derived" classes - because if you have this...

```
public class BaseService
{
    public BaseService( ILogger<BaseService> log )
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class DerivedService : BaseService
{
    // ...?
}
```

...you might wonder if a `DerivedService` is supposed to accept `ILogger<BaseService>` or `ILogger<DerivedService>` as surely it needs an `ILogger<BaseService>` to pass down to `BaseService`, but then `DerivedService` would lose its strongly-typed category name.

...but this is not the case! If you look at the definition of `ILogger<T>` you'll see it's a [**covariant generic interface** because it has `<out T>` rather than just `<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier). This means that any variable, method or constructor that accepts an `ILogger<Base>` will also accept an `ILogger<Derived>`!

So you have this and it's perfectly legal:

```
public class BaseService
{
    public BaseService( ILogger<BaseService> log )
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class DerivedService : BaseService
{
    public DerivedService( ILogger<DerivedService> log )
        : base( log ) // `ILogger<BaseService>` can accept an `ILogger<DerivedService>`!
    {
    }
}
```

And you can instantiate an instance of `DerivedService` or `BaseService` with a `NullLogger` as per my earlier example:

```
BaseService bs = new BaseService( NullLoggerFactory.Instance.CreateLogger<BaseService>() );

DerivedService ds = new DerivedService ( NullLoggerFactory.Instance.CreateLogger<DerivedService>() );
```

### Factory helper:

If you find yourself needing to make a `NullLogger` (or your own `ILogger` implementation) frequently then you can use this factory-helper method:

```
public static TService CreateServiceWithLogger<TService>( Func<ILogger<TService>,TService> ctor )
{
    ILogger<TService> log = NullLoggerFactory.Instance.CreateLogger<TService>();
    return ctor( log );
}
```

C#'s type-inference rules will ensure you won't need to provide an explicit `TService` generic parameter type argument, like so:

```
TurboEncabulatorService service = CreateServiceWithNullLogger( log => new TurboEncabulatorService( log ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Dependency Injection for this.

Your `Controller` leverages DI resources by referencing the interface in its constructor. For `ILogger<Class>` this would look this like:

```
public class MyAwesomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyAwesomeController(ILogger<MyAwesomeController> logger)
    {
        // logger contains a refference to the DIed ILogger 
        // We assign it to _logger so we can reference it from other
        // methods in the class
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult GetIndex()
    {
        // Log something
        //_logger.LogInformation();
        return View();
    }
}
```

You can find a lot more detail in the documentation: [Logging in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#how-to-create-logs)